# Trouble Adding Trendline to Chart in Excel 365 Excelscript

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, charts, office-scripts

I'm trying to automate emails with a line chart from some Microsoft Forms Data saving to Excel.

I've been able to create the bar chart via Excelscript and have the image returned to Flow, however I can't seem to find how to turn on the trendline via the script when creating the chart in Excel.

````js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  // Insert chart on sheet selectedSheet
  let chart_1 = selectedSheet.addChart(ExcelScript.ChartType.columnClustered, selectedSheet.getRange("A1:B165"));
  chart_1.getSeries()[1].addChartTrendline;
}```
````

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve].  We need to see the code you attempted.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
chart_1.getSeries()[0].addChartTrendline(ExcelScript.ChartTrendlineType.linear);
```